Accessibility problem in Google Drive API limited to shared drives
I am trying to retrieve the unique identifiers that Google Drive assigns to files (the last part of the url) in an automated way using a python script.
I created a service account and a service account key and I am using the Google Drive API to get that information. I would like to work using my work account and the shared drive with unlimited space that we have, but it seems I cannot access any of the files in there. If I try to use the same script in my personal account it works just fine, meaning that it is likely a policy and permission issue on the side of my administration. The folders themselves are viewable by anyone with the link and I also made the service account content manager of the folder. When I run my script on a shared google drive folder I don't get any error, it just looks like no files are in the folder. Also, it is worth mentioning that I included the supportsAllDrives=True statement, meaning the script should be able to access shared drives too.
My company is totally fine with changing the policies, but they don't know what to do and neither do I (also, I can't change policy settings from my account). This is my first time using Google Cloud Platform and it is a whole new world for me.
Does anyone know how to get rid of this problem? What policies might affect this?
Thanks a lot!

please edit your question and include [example]

First you need to configure Domain wide delegation on your service account
if your uploading you need to set the parents to the shared drive id, you also need to have SupportsAllDrives set to true
Let me know what method you are using i might have an example.
